# using spring transactionManager with Hibernate after transaction committed only one repository of two is actually being committed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a `@Transactional` method that changes the state of two entities of different, not related, repositories.

something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void foo() {
  A a = repoA.findById(1);
  a.setState(s1);
  B b = repoB.findById(1);
  b.setState(s2);
  // (and I also do repoA.save(a); and repoB.save(b); although it is redundant)
}
```

I also have a transactional method `bar` that calls `foo` and publishes an event that is being caught by a `TransactionalEventListener` like this:

```
@Transactional 
public void bar() {
  foo();
  applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new AppEvent(123));
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class MyApplicationEventListener {

    @TransactionalEventListener
    public void handleAfterCommit(AppEvent appEvent){
       //do something;
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that in 80% of the time when `handleAfterCommit` method is invoked, only `(A a )` is being committed but `(B b)` is losing its changes.

I need help to understand what is going on here, I tried to debug and explore the
`TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()` but didn't find any insights.

Thanks,
Eilon

Comment: You need to understand `isolation` and `propagation`. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_transaction_management.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, we are using a custom AttributeConverter and we didnt implement Equals for the relevant javav object, this caused every dirty check on select to fail and do a full update (overriding values that meanwhile have been changed)

Thanks